Pycharm is not finding my Pytest test suite
I'm running PyCharm Professional 2023.3.4 on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
My PyTests run OK from the command line. But running them from PyCharm produces this message: Empty suite.
I need to debug my tests, and would like to use the IDE. I've set Pycharm's default test runner to pytest. I suspect the problem may be in my congiguration; here's a screenshot of the relevant dialog.
How should I fill out this dialog to let Pycharm find my PyTest suite?
Thank you in advance for any help.


Based on the screenshot you provided above, here are the steps to set it up, and yes, it is your configuration that led to the empty suites you are getting, I believe:
Target Selection workaround:

Choose the target type from the drop-down: It can be via
Script: If you want to run a specific Python file or
Module: If you want to run a Python module (specify the module name). Looking at your screenshot closely, I believe you are using a module named Python tests, and I can't see __init__.py there, kindly create a file with that name (__init__.py) for the Python interpreter to
identify that it is a package, which will enable your Pytest suites to run.
or Custom: For an arbitrary combination of paths, modules, and test class instances.

Goodluck.

I added missing __init__.py's in tests/integration and tests/unit. I'm now using a Module target -- I selected it from the Module drop-down so I think it's correct. Running the pytest configuration in Pycharm gives me:
Testing started at 1:30 PM ... Launching pytest with arguments ...
followed by the correct arguments. Then comes a long traceback, none of which refers to my code. The traceback ends with
TypeError: <blabla> Process finished with exit code 1 Empty suite
Do you have any suggestions?

It's nice to hear that my solution to your problem worked for you @jazcap53. Kindly tick the answer I provided good, so that if someone has similar issue and stumble on your question, it will help him or her out. Thank you.

Hello, for the 2nd question you added, kindly create it separately because it is not part of the initial challenge or problem you faced, and tag me along it, and i will solve it for you. Thank you

Hi there, I would like to see your Pytest code if you have written one in the code. If not, then your Pycharm is waiting for you to start writing your test cases, thus leading to the error. Note that, exit code 0 means a code or your codes run successfuly with no error, while exit code 1 means it didn't run successful, there are some issues. Please don't forget to start the functions or classes you want to test with prefix test then followed by the name.
